# Zonal Statistics in QGIS 3.30

Tags: qgis, plugins

I can't find the plugin zonal Statistics anymore. Has it be renamed or is there something similar ?

Comment: You can't use the native tool? https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics

Comment: I can't install it. I already tried to install it manually, but it says 'This plugin is incompatible with this version of QGIS'. Do you know if there is a similar tool or has it been renamed ?

Comment: it's not a plugin, it's located in the processing toolbox

Comment: Great. Thank you. I found it.

Comment: Please, Flag the answer below to correct to help another users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the native tool Zonal Statistics

[image: native tool Zonal Statistics]